# Dynamically layout widgets based on the size/position of other widgets (sub-widgets)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'd like to draw a **graph of nodes and edges**. The graph should appear like a [forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Forest) of [trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Tree). To simplify my question, let's focus on a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Tree), which should be drawn like this:

[image]

I'm not in search of the algorithm, which computes positions of nodes on the drawing plane. Recursively computing sizes and positions of visual representations of a nodes / subtrees using [depth first tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) is trivial.

I'm in search of a [flutter](https://flutter.dev) implementation:

I suppose, a [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) and [Positioned](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) widgets would be fine for placing nodes.

- But how do I get the rendered size / dimension of a widget and recursively the dimension of a subtree?
- And how do I get this dimensions when the code is about to place nodes / subtrees using [Positioned](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) on Stack?

Could you please provide an example or a recipe?

**Update 2022-09-25**

As Randal Schwartz and PixelToast pointed out, [boxy](https://pub.dev/packages/boxy) is a great solution to meet my current goal. **Great solution created by @PixelToast!**

Nevertheless, I'll keep the question open, in case someone posts details regarding the rendering / measuring process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately these kinds of layouts are not possible in Flutter without lots of boilerplate and a custom [RenderObject](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderObject-class.html). I am the author of the [Boxy](https://pub.dev/packages/boxy) package which makes the process of creating one much simpler.

Here is a working solution:

[image]

```dart
class TreeNode {
  const TreeNode(this.widget, [this.children = const []]);

  final Widget widget;
  final List<TreeNode> children;

  Iterable<Widget> get allWidgets =>
      [widget].followedBy(children.expand((e) => e.allWidgets));
}

class TreeView extends StatelessWidget {
  const TreeView({
    required this.root,
    required this.verticalSpacing,
    required this.horizontalSpacing,
    super.key,
  });

  final TreeNode root;
  final double verticalSpacing;
  final double horizontalSpacing;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomBoxy(
      delegate: _TreeViewBoxy(
        root: root,
        verticalSpacing: verticalSpacing,
        horizontalSpacing: horizontalSpacing,
      ),
      children: [...root.allWidgets],
    );
  }
}

class _TreeViewBoxy extends BoxyDelegate {
  _TreeViewBoxy({
    required this.root,
    required this.verticalSpacing,
    required this.horizontalSpacing,
  });

  final TreeNode root;
  final double verticalSpacing;
  final double horizontalSpacing;

  @override
  Size layout() {
    var index = 0;
    Size visit(TreeNode node, Offset offset) {
      final nodeIndex = index++;
      final child = children[nodeIndex];
      final size = child.layout(const BoxConstraints());
      final Size subtreeSize;

      if (node.children.isEmpty) {
        subtreeSize = size;
      } else {
        var width = 0.0;
        var height = 0.0;
        var x = 0.0;
        final y = offset.dy + child.size.height + verticalSpacing;
        for (final child in node.children) {
          final childSize = visit(child, Offset(offset.dx + x, y));
          height = max(height, childSize.height);
          width += childSize.width;
          x += childSize.width + horizontalSpacing;
        }
        width += (node.children.length - 1) * horizontalSpacing;
        subtreeSize = Size(
          max(width, size.width),
          size.height + height + verticalSpacing,
        );
      }

      child.position(
        offset +
            Offset(
              subtreeSize.width / 2 - child.size.width / 2,
              0,
            ),
      );

      return subtreeSize;
    }

    return visit(root, Offset.zero);
  }

  @override
  void paint() {
    var index = 0;
    void paintLines(TreeNode node) {
      final nodeOffset = children[index++].rect.bottomCenter;
      for (final child in node.children) {
        final childOffset = children[index].rect.topCenter;
        canvas.drawPath(
          Path()
            ..moveTo(nodeOffset.dx, nodeOffset.dy)
            ..cubicTo(
              nodeOffset.dx,
              nodeOffset.dy + verticalSpacing,
              childOffset.dx,
              childOffset.dy - verticalSpacing,
              childOffset.dx,
              childOffset.dy,
            ),
          Paint()
            ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
            ..strokeWidth = 3.0,
        );
        paintLines(child);
      }
    }

    paintLines(root);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(_TreeViewBoxy oldDelegate) =>
      root != oldDelegate.root ||
      verticalSpacing != oldDelegate.verticalSpacing ||
      horizontalSpacing != oldDelegate.horizontalSpacing;
}
```

The full example can be found here: https://gist.github.com/PixelToast/3739dee678ee1b19e4d299c0025794b9

Comment: Great project, great sample code and great documentation! Thank you very mich, PixelToast! Going to use boxy. Keeping the question open, in case someone would like to provide details.

Comment: Would this be possible, in case alle nodes have the same size: Layout one node off-screen, retrieve its rendered size and then render the whole tree onscreen?

Comment: Yep, you can lay out a child, call ignore, and then use their size in BoxConstraints.tight for the rest of the children.

Answer (score 1):

You want the [Boxy](https://pub.dev/packages/boxy) package in the Pub.  There's even an example of a hierarchical set of widgets being displayed in the Examples.

Comment: @randal-schartz Great! This is exactly what I'm in search of: https://i.tst.sh/sYQHo.png

Comment: But nevertheless, I'd be too happy, if someone could explain the underlying mechanics. Or even better provide some code sample.

Comment: There is plenty of documentation.  Be sure you're reading the boxy wiki for core concepts and examples.  And then download the source repo and look at the source for the examples.

Comment: Sure, I'll do. Besides solving my current (spare time) technical goal, just wanted to dive a bit deeper in Flutter's internal workings. Thus my question.

Answer (score 0):

This partial solution layouts Nodes like so:

[image]

Unfortunately, drawing edges might not be possible. Nevertheless...

Structure of nodes:

```
Node AA = Node( title: 'AA' );
Node ABA = Node( title: 'ABA' );
Node ABB = Node( title: 'ABB' );
Node ABC = Node( title: 'ABC' );
Node AB = Node( title: 'AB', children: [ ABA, ABB, ABC ]  );
Node AC = Node( title: 'AC'  );
Node AD = Node( title: 'AD'  );
Node root = Node( title: 'A', children: [ AA, AB, AC, AD ] );
```

Calling the layout:

```
TreeViewSample( root: root )
```

TreeViewSample:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Node {
  Node({required this.title, this.children = const []});

  String title = '-';

  List<Node> children = [];
}

/**
 * Layouts Nodes like a tree, root at the top of the drawing area
 */
class TreeViewSample extends StatefulWidget {
  TreeViewSample({Key? key, required this.root}) : super(key: key);

  Node root;

  @override
  State<TreeViewSample> createState() => _TreeViewSampleState();
}

class _TreeViewSampleState extends State<TreeViewSample> {
  TextStyle style = TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if ( widget.root.children.isEmpty ) {
      return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Text(widget.root.title, style: style));
    } else {
      return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Container(child: Text(widget.root.title, style: style)),
                SizedBox(height: 5),
                Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(top: BorderSide(color: Colors.white))),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          ...widget.root.children
                              .map((e) => TreeViewSample(root: e))
                        ])),
              ]));
    }
  }
}
```