# Retrieve the dimensions of a rendered widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Suppose a [Widget](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets-intro) has a varying size based on certain properties of the underlying data structure.

**May I render a [Widget](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets-intro) offscreen just to measure  its width and height?**

How would I do that?

**Update - 2020-09-25**

I need the dimensions of one rendered widget to assign correct dimension to compute and assign dimensions to the items in a widget tree to get rendered.

Thus I need to retrieve dimensions before I use them in the widget tree.

Comment: you can use `CustomSingleChild Layout`

Comment: Helpful. Unfortunately, the docs explain this: 'but the size of the parent cannot depend on the size of the child'. Since I want to layout tree, the parent need to size as big as the Childs of the subtree.

Comment: so most likely `boxed` package would be helpful - the docs say: "This is essentially a more powerful version of CustomMultiChildLayout or CustomPaint, it allows you to inflate, constrain, and lay out each child manually, it also allows its size to depend on the layout of its children."

Comment: Might flow be helpful:? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flow-class.html

Comment: Yes, boxy would do a great job. https://pub.dev/packages/boxy - Just fiddling around to see / learn if something else would be possible. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73840748/dynamically-layout-widgets-based-on-the-size-position-of-other-widgets-sub-widg

Comment: of course something else would be possible - a custom [RenderBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderBox-class.html) ;-)

Comment: check `ContainerRenderObjectMixin` for more info on how to implement `RenderBox` with multiple children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a widget (either visible or not, use the `Opacity` widget to hide it if necessary), give it a `GlobalKey`, and then use that key to get its render object, then get the size from it.

For example, I added 3 lines of code, to the default "flutter counter example" project. Now clicking on the floating action button will print out the size of the column.

> Sample output: Size(297.0, 741.0)

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey(); // <--- 1. add this line
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
    print(_key.currentContext?.size);  // <--- 2. add this line
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          key: _key,  // <--- 3. add this line
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```